Blazor - How to prevent custom component being rendered in base component
I have developed some component in Blazor. All of them are inherited from BaseComponent.
public abstract class BaseComponent : ComponentBase
{
    [Parameter]
    public bool Visible { get; set; } = true;

    // Other properties ....
}

The Visible property should control if the derived components should be rendered or not.
I want all of derived components have the visibly feature (instead of writing if block in all of the components.
How can I prevent the components being rendered in base component?

You need to:

Prevent the parent from rendering the component
Prevent any internal calls to StateHasChanged rendering the component

You can do that like this:
public abstract class BaseComponent : ComponentBase
{
    [Parameter] public bool Visible { get; set; } = true;

    // Prevents rendering from the parent
    public override Task SetParametersAsync(ParameterView parameters)
    {
        parameters.SetParameterProperties(this);

        if (this.Visible)
            return base.SetParametersAsync(ParameterView.Empty);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    // Prevents rendering if StateHasChanged is called
    protected override bool ShouldRender()
    {
        return this.Visible;
    }
}

Update based on further use case comments.
This is not possible without some contorted code using ComponentBase.  It wasn't designed that way.
The simplest solution is to create a separate Show/Hide component that you wrap your code in.
If you want to build the functionality into your component you need to use or create a new ComponentBase.  In which case, this article explains how - https://shauncurtis.github.io/Articles/The-Three-Component-Solution.html

Thanks. There is an issue: if the derived component's Visible is set to true, and in some trigger (ie Button click) we set it to false, it will be Visible again. Changing visibility from true to false in C# code is not working.

Here is my sample:
`<Button @onclick="ToggleAlert">Toggle alert
Some text
@code {
private bool AlertVisible { get; set; } = false;
private void ToggleAlert()
{
AlertVisible = !AlertVisible;
}
}`

See additional information in the answer.
